# How to start to recognize object in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

My final goal is to dynamically recognize different object which is 2D and often has same appearance(2D deck game) in video. I was studying opencv-python tutorial, but there aren't any topic about this, so I want to know what topic, library or function should I learn to reach my goal. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting for this question to be closed as too broad as it is formulated right now. There are plenty of tutorials on object recognition using OpenCV. You should actually try something out and come back as soon as you have an specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try several Machine Learning techniques. You may get inspiration from [Viola-Jones](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=viola%20jones%20rapid%20object%20detection&btnG=) or [Histograms of Oriented Gradients + SVM](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=histograms%20of%20oriented%20gradients%20for%20human%20detection&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart) algorithms (even though those algorithms solve a problem that may differ yours, I had plenty of insights from them). In other words, try "sliding" a window along a horizontal and vertical axes of predefined aspect ratio and try to recognize the Region Of Interest with a model of your choice (CNN, SVM, Logistic Regression etc.). But the problem may be that you will need to train a model, which may require a lot of data.

Or you can do a template matching, which is more of Image Processing problem rather than Machine Learning. It would not require dataset and training, but it will be sensitive to noises, lighting, and position.

Good luck!